# Navbar content moving around when resizing

Tags: html, css, mobile, resize, navbar

i have an issue with my navbar, when i resize it to a smaller resolution, it starts to move around i just want it to get smaller but staying still, i got some suggestions of making the items in the left section of the navbar smaller, but hope i could find other solution, because i seen websites that dont have this issue in their navbar.

```
<nav>
        <ul>
                <li class="topnav-left"><a href="#home"><img src="Img/Emg.png" alt="Logo" width="100" height="100"></a></li>
                <li class="name"><a href="#home"><h1>Magnificent<span class="h2r"> Gaming</span></h1></a></li> 
        </ul>
        <ul class="topnav" id="dropdownclick">
            <li class="center"><a href="#home"><b>Home</b></a></li>
            <li class="center"><a href="#teams"><b>Teams</b></a></li>
            <li class="center"><a href="#sponsors"><b>Sponsors</b></a></li>
            <li class="center"><a href="#contact"><b>Contact</b></a></li>
            <li class="triline"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="dropdownmenu()">&#9776;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">


    </div>

    <script>
    function dropdownmenu() {
        var x = document.getElementById("dropdownclick");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
            /*change topnav to topnav.responsive*/ 
        } else{
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
    }
    </script>


    nav {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    li.topnav-left{
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 40px;
    }

    nav ul.topnav {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        padding-right: 50px;
        float: right;
    }

    ul.topnav li {
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        padding-top: 37.2px;
    }

    li.topnav-left {
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 30px;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }

    ul.topnav li a{
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size: 19px;
        padding: 14px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
       }

       .center::after{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 2px;
        background: #fff;
        transition: width .3s;
       }

       .center:hover::after{
        width: 100%;
        transition: width .3s;
       }

    li.name a{
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        float: left;
        padding-top: 32px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .h2r{
        color: black;
        text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, 1px 1px #fff, -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff;
    }

    li.name{
        list-style: none;
    }

    ul.topnav li.triline {
        display: none;
    }


    @media screen and (max-width: 995px) {
        ul.topnav li  {
    display: none;
         } 

         ul.topnav li.triline { 
             display: block; 
             float: right; 
             top: 40px;
             right: 50px;
         } 

         ul.topnav.responsive li.triline {
             position: absolute;
             top:0;
             right: 58px;
         }

     ul.topnav.responsive { 
         position: relative; 
         float: right;
         padding-top: 75px;
       } 

         ul.topnav.responsive li { 
          display: inline; 
          float: none; 
         } 

         ul.topnav.responsive li a{ 
             display: block; 
            text-align: right;   
         }
    }
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the code instead of using images. It helps users stay on StackOverflow without too much context switching. SO formats code consistently across all questions.

Comment: its very hard to put the code here, im sorry that i posted pictures instead

Comment: Post your chunk of code, select it & press Ctrl+K to format it. Code is better if you want your question answered.

Comment: If you want to get a solution It's better you take some time and put the code here. Many won't likely to look into the question if you put code as images. Those who need to give you an answer can re use the code if you put it here

Comment: thanks guys, i updated the post with the css code